# Android - Textview + Button opens twitter app and enters text as status

Tags: android

I know this is possible, and I have seen it done, I just do not know how to do it myself, or where to find documentation.

I want it so the user can enter text in a textfield, and then push a button, and it opens the official Twitter for Android app, and puts the text entered in the textfield, into the status update on the Twitter app.

If you are wondering where I have seen this done, it is with the CNN app (and other news apps), where you click share, you can choose twitter and it puts the link and headline as a status update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses an Intent to launch the Twitter Android app: take a look at http://lisudza.wordpress.com/2010/12/29/tweeting-using-twitter-for-android-intent/ and see if it covers what you want.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something like that, but I totally blanked on what it was called!

Comment: @user802609 can you help me i have the same problem, do i need some external api to use this code if yes what would be that,because this link does not seems to have the complete code,where i can find more